# Twig get object names ending with numbers dynamically

Tags: twig

I have some objects like address1, address2, address3 ... address10. All these objects have `lat` and `long` values.

I know we can get it from the `attribute()` function of Twig, but what I want in my twig template is to get the main objects

```
 {% for i in 1..10 %}
      {% set address = address~i %}
      {{ address.lat }}
      // or like
      {{ attribute(address, 'lat') }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply use :

```
 {% for i in 1..10 %}
      {{ attribute(attribute(_context, 'address'~i), 'lat') }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks @Raphaël Vigée it worked... just another question, is there any documentation on this _context attribute?

Comment: You're welcome ! I haven't found a full documentation, but it's the main variable where all the others are standing in.